# Any way to make DataContractJsonSerializer serialize Dictionaries properly?

Tags: .net, wcf, serialization

The DataContractJsonSerializer is not able to serialize Dictionaries properly.

Whereas JavaScriptSerializer serializes Dictionaries as `{"abc":"xyz","def":42}` 
for example,
the DataContractJsonSerializer gives `[{"Key":"abc","Value":"xyz"},{"Key":"def","Value":42}]` instead.

This is really problematic and I want to know how can I serialize Dictionary objects correctly in my WCF service. I am looking for a solution that would require least amount of effort.

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx

This is the workaround I finally used to serilize dictionaries properly in WCF: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/765f1569-0422-4471-8ec2-1d03b2026771

Comment: If you are not using Json.NET, see this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498208/serialize-dictionarytkey-tvalue-to-json-with-datacontractjsonserializer

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Using [DataContractJsonSerializerSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings(v=vs.110).aspx) (available since .NET 4.5) can do this for you:

```
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeOfObj, new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings()
{
    UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true 
});
```

Comment: Hi, where can I replace the "normal" serializer with this serializier when I am create the service host in code?

Answer (score 29):

Unfortunately this appears to be by-design, according to the section "Collections, Dictionaries, and Arrays" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx

> All collections, dictionaries, and arrays are represented in JSON as **arrays.**

Answer (score 10):

Although this will in most cases cause a major rewrite and thus not be feasible you can let your WCF service interface accept and return `Stream` in which case you can take full control of serialization. This way you can use `JavaScriptSerializer`, [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) or [ServiceStack.JSON](https://github.com/ServiceStack/) to perform the actual serialization and these serializers actually deals with a dictionaries in a more sensible way.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean string instead of stream?

Comment: @Markus: No, I did not. A string doesn't give you control over the serialization, it gives the method a signature forcing some kind of stirng input whereas `Stream` by convention instructs WCF that you want to take control over serialization. I don't think these two solutions are interchangeable.

Comment: Hmm... i assumed that a return type of string wouldn't be processed either, which seems not to be the case? Otherwise using stream instead of string would by unwieldy, IMO.

Comment: I guess it depends: If you are using Xml style serialization it will be wrapped. Json (which is of course the pivot of this question) is perhaps another questions since you may get it to work. This doesn't change that WCF has a special use of Streams as both input and return types. It is mainly due to performance issues, but control about serialization is also a point. (WCF simply stops all serialization interceptions and leaves it to you why it is also faster than having WCF intercept your suggested string whereupon you do a different serialization.)

Comment: Correct, Stream would perform better than a string (as the string would not be subject to the serialization phase) and would guarantee byte for byte that the payload remains unchanged by WCF formatting and serialization. Granted, other stages could modify it, but not in so far as serialization goes. This is a pragmatic solution to the problem.

Answer (score 8):

`DataContractJsonSerializerSettings` has the `UseSimpleDictionaryFormat` property now and it serializes dictionaries the way you'd expect.

Comment: Where can I replace the "normal" serializer with this serializier when I am creating the service host in code?