# How to de-serialize a json object containing variable number of objects and get them as a key value collection in C#?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

How can I deserialize the following JSON object and get a collection of Dictionary where the key(string) should be the method name and the object the details in C#.

```
{
"methods": {
    "password.2": {
      "title": "Password CustomerID",
      "type": "password"
    },
    "ubikey.sms.1": {
      "title": "SMS",
      "type": "stepup",
      "password": "password.2",
      "stepUp": "sms"
    },
    "tupas.test.1": {
      "title": "TUPAS Emulator",
      "type": "proxy"
    }
  }
}
```

If it was an array of methods, I could have easily serialized it using an array. But since that itself is a key value pair, I'm stuck.

I'm making an WebRequest to a particular api and getting the result as a json.

The code used to serialize the object is from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674188.aspx

Comment: what purpose you want the dictionary for? you could easily parse the json and get typed object in c#

Comment: By method name you mean "password.2", "ubikey.sms.1","tupas.test.1" ?

Comment: As an object also, when parsing the above json, it results in an object, containing a each method as a separate property. The number of methods can vary. I need a list of objects each containing the method name and their details.

Comment: What version of .net framework are you using?

Comment: @Alireza .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: I was about a solution as TLJ posted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you [linked to](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674188.aspx) describes how to use [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to deserialize JSON.  You can use that serializer to deserialize your `"methods"` object as a `Dictionary`, *provided you are using .Net 4.5 or later* and also set [`DataContractJsonSerializerSettings.UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings.usesimpledictionaryformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Having done this, you can define the following classes:

```
public class Method
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string stepUp { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public Dictionary<string, Method> methods { get; set; }
}
```

And parse them as follows:

```
        var settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings { UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true };
        var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Response), settings);
        var jsonResponse = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream()) as Response;
```

If you are using an earlier version of .Net, you may need to use a different serializer such as [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializingjson.htm), since, in earlier versions, `DataContractJsonSerializer` serializes dictionaries as [key/value pair arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559991/any-way-to-make-datacontractjsonserializer-serialize-dictionaries-properly).

Comment: Thanks, worked.. Decided to go with this method since I can avoid the JSON.net dependancy..

Answer (score 2):

JSON.net does this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = @"{
""methods"": {
    ""password.2"": {
      ""title"": ""Password CustomerID"",
      ""type"": ""password""
    },
    ""ubikey.sms.1"": {
      ""title"": ""SMS"",
      ""type"": ""stepup"",
      ""password"": ""password.2"",
      ""stepUp"": ""sms""
    },
    ""tupas.test.1"": {
      ""title"": ""TUPAS Emulator"",
      ""type"": ""proxy""
    }
  }
}";

            Dictionary<string, Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,String>>> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,String>>>>(json);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 dynamic results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonString());
 Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
 foreach (var o in results.methods)
 {
     dictionary[o.Name] = o.Value;
 }

private static string JsonString()
{
         return "{\"methods\": {\"password.2\": {\"title\": \"Password CustomerID\",\"type\": \"password\"},\"ubikey.sms.1\": {\"title\": \"SMS\",\"type\": \"stepup\",\"password\": \"password.2\",\"stepUp\": \"sms\"},\"tupas.test.1\": {\"title\": \"TUPAS Emulator\",\"type\": \"proxy\"}}}";
}
```