# How to deserialize custom json in C#

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to deserialize a JSON file which elements are in the following format:

```
{"include\\fooo\\Gell.h": {
    "parents": [
        "include\\rfg\\ExplorableMa.h"
    ],
    "children": [
        "include\\rfg\\IEditable.h",
        "include\\rfg\\IExplorable.h",
        "Bar"
    ]
}}
```

There may be 1 or more elements following each other in the JSON file. I tried using the `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json` namespace, but I did not have much success with this code:

```
[DataContract]
class Vertex
{
    [DataMember] public string Path { get; set; }
}

using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(@"file.json"))
{
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Vertex[]));
    Vertex[] verteces = (Vertex[])serializer.ReadObject(stream);
    // the array is not valid at this point
}
```

The code above is supposed to fill the array with a single vertex and its path equal to `"include\\fooo\\Gell.h"` in this specific case to start.
What is the correct way to deserialize such a JSON file?

Comment: Have you heard of `Json.net`?

Comment: @dbc I edited the json, now it is valid.

Comment: @FrankerZ No, I didn't. I would prefer to not use 3rd party libraries. How come does it have to be so difficult to parse JSON in .Net? Such a standard format.

Comment: Why not use a well supported 3rd party library? And why are you trying to deserialize to a Vertex array? And why doesn't your object you're to deserialize match the JSON stucture? I see no Path property in your JSON.

Comment: @mason what would be the name of the property in the Vertex class considering that each element can have a different name?

Comment: Use Newtonsoft.Json. It is a 3d party, it is an Asp.Net mvc core dependency though. Worth to be considered reliable.

Comment: The name is the least your worries. The JSON and the class you're deserializing to are wildly different. You'd need a class that has a Parents property and a children property. Each of those would likely be an array of strings. You really need to think about how the object should be represented in C# instead of just making up a random class and hoping it will serialize/deserialize. You're saying "why is it so difficult to parse JSON in .NET" when the reality is you're making it difficult.

Comment: Have a look at [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) which does a passable job of generating an appropriate C# class based on some JSON.

Comment: @mason having parents and children properties are not sufficient, that name is the problem, how do I represent it in the Vertex class?

Comment: Which version of .Net are you using?  If you are using .Net 4.5 you can deserialize to a dictionary with `DataContractJsonSerializer` by setting `UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27223290/3744182).  If not it will be very difficult to use `DataContractJsonSerializer`.  Either way [tag:json.net] could be a better choice.

Comment: @dbc How would I deserialize it with json.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, note that your root JSON container is an object, not an array.  The [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/) specifies the following types of container:

- The array which an ordered collection of values. An array begins with `[` (left bracket) and ends with `]` (right bracket). Values are separated by `,` (comma).

  Most JSON serializers map .Net enumerables to JSON arrays.
- The object which is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with `{` (left brace) and ends with `}` (right brace).

  Most JSON serializers map dictionaries and non-enumerable, non-primitive types to JSON objects.

Thus you will need to deserialize to a different type, one which maps to an object with custom, variable property names that have values with fixed schema.  Most serializers support to `Dictionary<string, TValue>` in such situations.

First define the following type:

```
public class VertexData
{
    public List<string> parents { get; set; }
    public List<string> children { get; set; }
}
```

Then, using [datacontractjsonserializer](/questions/tagged/datacontractjsonserializer) you can deserialize to a `Dictionary<string, VertexData>` as follows *as long as you are using .Net 4.5 or later* as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27223290/3744182):

```
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Dictionary<string, VertexData>)) { UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true };
var vertices = (Dictionary<string, VertexData>)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
var paths = vertices.Keys.ToList();
```

If you would prefer to use [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net) you can [deserialize](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm) to the same `Dictionary<string, VertexData>` as follows:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
{
    var vertices = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, VertexData>>(jsonReader);
    var paths = vertices.Keys.ToList();
}
```

And finally with [javascriptserializer](/questions/tagged/javascriptserializer):

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    var jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();

    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var vertices = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, VertexData>>(jsonString);
    var paths = vertices.Keys.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Json.Net you could deserialize your file in this way (or similar):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Vertex
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public IDictionary<string, JToken> _additionalData;
}

var content = File.ReadAllText(@"file.json");
var d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Vertex>(content);
```

Have a look at these examples: http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2013/05/08/json-net-5-0-release-5-defaultsettings-and-extension-data