# Output a JSON property name with a dash using an anonymous object

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I am using a third party API which is like this below. It uses `Json serializer` to output

`public Output(string name, object value);`

I have to place the following json string in my output file from C#

`Output("somename", new {my-name : "somevalue"})`

The issue is C# does not allow identifiers with dash (-). How do I achieve this ?

Tried putting raw value like below but it adds `back slash (\)` to the file output which is not going very well.

`Output("somename", @"{""my-name"":""somevalue""}")`

Any thoughts ?

Comment: What third party serializer, i am having a lot of trouble understanding this question, however it could be just me

Comment: Why not just use a dictionary?  `new Dictionary<string, string> { { "my-name", "somevalue" } }`

Comment: Since you have tagged this [tag:json.net], it is probably a duplicate of [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24536533/3744182).  Agree?

Comment: @dbc put it as answer. That works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using an anonymous object, the simplest workaround would be to create a `Dictionary<string, string>` instead:

```
Output("somename", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "my-name", "somevalue" } });
```

Serialization of a dictionary as a JSON object in which the dictionary keys are mapped to JSON property names is supported by many .Net JSON serializers including [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net) and [javascriptserializer](/questions/tagged/javascriptserializer) and even [datacontractjsonserializer](/questions/tagged/datacontractjsonserializer) when [`UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializersettings.usesimpledictionaryformat?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Runtime_Serialization_Json_DataContractJsonSerializerSettings_UseSimpleDictionaryFormat) as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4559991/3744182).

And if you have values of different types and are using a serializer that supports arbitrary polymorphism during serialization (Json.NET and `JavaScriptSerializer` do) you could use a `Dictionary<string, object>`:

```
Output("somename",
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "my-name", "somevalue" },
        { "my-id", 101 },
        { "my-value", value },
    });
```