# Serialisation of custom type inheriting Dictionary using System.Text.Json does not serialise other properties

Tags: c#, json, serialization, .net-5, system.text.json

I have the following type:

```
public class Product : Dictionary<string, object>
{
    [JsonInclude]
    public string ProductId { get; set; }

    public Product(string productId) : base()
    {
        ProductId = productId;
    }
}
```

When serialising using System.Text.Json it does not include the properties (ie `ProductId`).
Adding or removing the `[JsonInclude]` does not seem to make any effect.

Test case:

```
[Fact]
public void SimpleTest()
{
    var p = new Product("ABC123");
    p["foo"] = "bar";
    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(p);
    Assert.Contains("productId", json, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

And output received:

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

How do I make it include my custom properties on my type during serialisation? (note: don't care about deserialisation).

Comment: How would you expect this to output?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  `System.Text.Json` only serializes the dictionary keys and values not the c# properties, as 1) there might be a key with the same name as a property, and 2) You probably don't want the "standard" properties like `Count` and `IsReadOnly` to be serialized.  I can't find anywhere in the MSFT docs where this is stated, however Newtonsoft is [documented to behave this way](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#ComplexTypes) as is `DataContractJsonSerializer` and `JavaScriptSerializer`. `System.Text.Json` seems to have followed precedent.

Comment: You might consider a different data model where `Product` doesn't inherit from `Dictionary` but instead has a `[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonExtensionData] public Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }` property.  The [`[JsonExtensionData]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonextensiondataattribute?view=net-5.0) attribute causes the dictionary properties to be included as part of the parent object when serializing.

Comment: Other than that you will need to write a custom `JsonConverter`.  (According to the [docs for `JsonInclude`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonincludeattribute?view=net-5.0) *When applied to a property, indicates that non-public getters and setters can be used for serialization and deserialization.*  So it isn't relevant here as `ProductId` already has public getters and setters.)

Comment: @dbc Actually the JsonExtensionData attribute might do the trick, I'll check it out, thanks. Submit it as an answer and I'll accept

Comment: @dbc This worked perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`System.Text.Json` does not serialize dictionary properties.**
I can't find anywhere in the MSFT docs where this is stated, but `System.Text.Json` only serializes the dictionary keys and values. This can be confirmed from the reference source for [`DictionaryOfTKeyTValueConverter<TCollection, TKey, TValue>`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v5.0.9/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/Converters/Collection/DictionaryOfTKeyTValueConverter.cs#L32), which is the converter used for your type.

This is likely because:

1. There might be a key with the same name as a property.
2. App developers almost certainly don't want the "standard" dictionary properties like `Count` and `IsReadOnly` to be serialized.
3. Earlier serializers behave the same way and `System.Text.Json` is following precedent.  Newtonsoft is [documented to only serialize dictionary keys and values](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#ComplexTypes).  `DataContractJsonSerializer` (with [`UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53416757/3744182)) and `JavaScriptSerializer` do also.

**As an alternative**, you might consider a different data model where `Product` doesn't inherit from `Dictionary` but instead has a `[JsonExtensionData] public Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }` property:

```cs
public class Product 
{
    public string ProductId { get; set; }

    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; } = new ();

    public Product(string productId) : base()
    {
        ProductId = productId;
    }
}
```

The [`[JsonExtensionData]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonextensiondataattribute?view=net-5.0) attribute causes the dictionary properties to be included as part of the parent object when serializing and deserializing.

Notes:

- If the suggested alternative is not acceptable, you will need to write a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#sample-factory-pattern-converter) to manually serialize the .NET properties and keys and values of your `Product` dictionary.
- Adding `[JsonInclude]` to `ProductId` will not force it to get serialized.  According to the [docs for `JsonInclude`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonincludeattribute?view=net-5.0), *When applied to a property, [it] indicates that non-public getters and setters can be used for serialization and deserialization.*  So it isn't relevant here as `ProductId` already has public getters and setters.
- Newtonsoft also has a [`JsonExtensionData`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeExtensionData.htm) attribute (which does the same thing).  If you are using both serializers, be careful to use the correct attribute.
- In your question you state *don't care about deserialisation* but deserialization does work correctly with `JsonExtensionData`.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QoRTY7).